# SQL replace data in table1 from table2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hello i have 2 tables in MySQL DB

```
status
id,    name,    date,    status
1      server1  datum    0
2      server2  datum    999
3      server3  datum    999
4      server4  datum    0

cis
id,    ,url
0      img/offline.png
1      img/server1.png
2      img/server2.png
3      img/server3.png
4      img/server4.png
999    img/online.png
```

i want to select id and status from status and i want to replace both server_id a and status with url from cis. But i dont know fi this is posible to do or do i need to create a third table for the online/ofline url?

i want to join the tables so that the select returns as this

```
id,              status  
img/server1.png, img/offline.png
img/server2.png, img/online.png
img/server3.png, img/online.png
img/server4.png, img/offline.png
```

Comment: Difficult to select `server_id` from `status` table when it has no such column.

Comment: Ah sorry its not server_id just id, my bad.

Comment: Are you asking for a `JOIN` query so you can see `id`, `status`, and `url` in a single row? Or are you asking if you need to create a new table to physically store those together? If the second, then yes (of course!).

Comment: Then *edit* the question and correct it!!!

Comment: *"i want to join the tables so that the select returns as this"* Then I suggest you **learn SQL**, instead of asking us to write the SQL query for you. The section you need to focus on is about **joins**, and it is taught by any decent SQL tutorial or training guide. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: That is what im triing to do the whole day but nothing i came up is working.

Comment: select s.id,s.name,s.date,s.status,c1.url as serverurl,c2.url as statusurl
from status s
left join cis c1 on s.id=c1.id
left join cis c2 on s.status=c2.id

Comment: Then if you'd read the link I provided in my first comment, you'd have known to edit the question and put that query into the question, to show your attempt, but I guess that was just too much work to read it, including this little gem: *What to do next: If we have made an effort, we should immediately **edit our question to detail exactly what we did**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, you tried the following query:

```
select s.id,s.name,s.date,s.status,c1.url as serverurl,c2.url as statusurl 
from status s left join cis c1 on s.id=c1.id left join cis c2 on s.status=c2.id
```

This returns the correct resultset, but if I understand what you are looking for, you want this query:

```
SELECT  c1.url AS id, c2.url AS status FROM `status` s
LEFT JOIN `cis` c1 ON s.id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN `cis` c2 ON s.status = c2.id
```

`c1.url` is aliased as `id` and `c2.url` is aliased as `status`